# What is a safe way to use pointers as keys for an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a project, I have data objects `XXData` and objects which represent these objects visually `XXDataVisual`. There can be up to 10'0000 objects which need to be loosely coupled. Only the `XXDataVisual` knows the represented `XXData`.

```
@interface XXDataVisual
@property (strong) XXData *data;
@end
```

The `XXData` must not know it's visual representation:

```
@interface XXData
// Elements
@end
```

To manage the visual representations, I need an efficient lookup which visual representation exists for a given data element.

Can I use the pointer of the `XXData` instances as a key to safely identify the the data elements?

Which is the best approach using modern Objective-C and Cocoa?

Comment: Assign a number to each XXData object (store it in the object) and use the NSNumber for the key.

Comment: This is what I currently do. But the creation of new unique numbers needs time, and storing this value in the XXData object needs memory. If I could use the pointer of the XXData object as unique identifier, it would solve these two problems. But I'm unsure if this is possible and recommended to do.

Comment: Have you profiled and found the creation of unique numbers to be a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: @andyvn22 Yes I did, and yes it was a bottleneck (because of the synchronisation and the copy operations). It also added 8 bytes of data to each object. The `NSMapTable` solved not only these problems, it simplified also the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NSMutableDictionary` is bad idea. It copies keys, so your memory usage will increase dramatically. Use `NSMapTable`. You can configure it to use non-copyable keys and storing weak references to values, for example:

```
NSMapTable *mapTable = [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory 
                                             valueOptions:NSMapTableWeakMemory];
```

Comment: I'm currently checking this approach.

Answer (score 2):

To have an NSDictionary-type collection where your keys are pointers, you might be needing an [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMapTable/setObject%3aforKey%3a) class.

From [this link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/nsmaptable-more-than-nsdictionary-for.html):

> NSMapTable (as the name implies) is more suited to mapping in a
>   general sense. Depending on how it is constructed, NSMapTable can
>   handle the "key-to-object" style mapping of an NSDictionary but it can
>   also handle "object-to-object" mappings — also known as an
>   "associative array" or simply a "map".